# Como minimizar Frame principal ao abrir um novo frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Estou com um probleminha, criei uma aplicação em java com um menu que chama varias telas. Ao abrir alguma tela, queria que a minha tela principal da aplicação fosse minimizada. Tentei com `setvisible(false)` porém não resultou no esperado.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um construtor nas telas secundárias, recebendo um JFrame como parâmetro, algo assim:

```
public JanelaSecundaria(Frame frame)  {

    //...

    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);

    //...
}
```

E na hora de instanciar suas janelas secundarias dentro do Frame principal, passe-o como referencia:

```
JanelaSecundaria j2 = new JanelaSecundaria(this);
```

Comment: Amigo, tentei colocar no construtor da tela que irá ser aberta e também no metodo que chama a tela e não funcionou

Comment: @ViniciusLeonardo veja a edição, se agora funciona corretamente.

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou exatamente, obrigado!